# add dynamic captions to video element

Tags: javascript, html, video, closed-captions

I want to allow the user to upload a subtitles file (e.g. ".srt") to play along an mp4 using plain HTML and JS.

I've tried everything I could think of, but am now out of ideas:

1) Tried setting the `src` attribute on a `track` child element of the `video` element

2) Tried creating a new `track` element in JS, setting the `src` attribute, and appending the `track` as a child of the `video` element

3) Tried using the `HTMLMediaElement.addTextTrack()` api of the `video` element, though the `TextTrack` api doesn't seem to support a `src` attribute.

4) Tried all these approaches with all combinations of `src`, `srcObject` (though I don't think this property is valid for `track` elements), and `URL.createObjectURL`.

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

$('#subtitles-input').addEventListener('change', () => {
  // approach 1
  $('#subtitles').src = URL.createObjectURL($('#subtitles-input').files[0]);

  // approach 2
  let track = document.createElement('track');
  track.kind = 'captions';
  track.label = 'English';
  track.srclang = 'en';
  track.src = URL.createObjectURL($('#subtitles-input').files[0]);
  track.mode = 'showing';
  $('#video').appendChild(track);
});
```

```html
<lablel>Subtitles: <input id="subtitles-input" type="file"></lablel>

<video id="video" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" controls>
 <track id="subtitles" kind="subtitles" label="English captions" srclang="en" default>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, my problem was using an `.srt` format instead of a `.vtt` format.

They're almost identical, adding `WEBVTT` as the first line and replacing `,`'s used to indicate milliseconds with `.`'s is sufficient to convert a valid `srt` file to a valid `vtt` file. Though `vtt`s seem to have additional optional features such as text formatting.

For what it's worth, approaches 1 and 2 worked equally well. Approach 3 and 4 don't work for the same reason mentioned above: `TextTrack` api doesn't support a `src` property `srcObject` is not a valid `track` element attribute, and `src` requires `URL.createObjectURL(file)`.

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

$('#subtitles-input').addEventListener('change', () => {
  // approach 1
  $('#subtitles').src = URL.createObjectURL($('#subtitles-input').files[0]);

  // approach 2
  let track = document.createElement('track');
  track.src = URL.createObjectURL($('#subtitles-input').files[0]);
  $('#video').appendChild(track);
});
```

```html
<lablel>Subtitles: <input id="subtitles-input" type="file"></lablel>

<video id="video" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" controls>
 <track id="subtitles" kind="subtitles" label="English captions" srclang="en" default>
</video>
```